# Negative or oversized stl deque?

Tags: c++, indexing, deque

I have deque and want to iter it backwards. I also need the index (otherwise I'd use the reverse_iterator) so I tried:

```
if ( _children.size( ) > 0 ) // debugging purpose
{
    unsigned si( _children.size( ) ); // debugging purpose
    int s( _children.size( ) - 1 ); // debugging purpose
    for ( unsigned c ( 0 ) ; c < _children.size( ) ; ++c )
        if ( this->_children[ ( _children.size( ) - 1 ) - c ]->Topmost( ) && 
             this->_children[ ( _children.size( ) - 1 ) - c ]->BorderRectangle( ).IsIn( X , Y ) )
               return std::pair< int, WindowPointer >( ( _children.size( ) - 1 ) - c, this->_children[ ( _children.size( ) - 1 ) - c ]->WindowAt( x, y ) );
```

but I get a sigsev. After debugging I get that index was -65. I checked the _children.size( ) by

```
unsigned si = _children.size( );
```

and it is 4294967232. And

```
long s = _children.size( ) - 1;
```

is -65. How do I get such values? And how to fix this?

Comment: Show your actual code (a minimal version that shows the same bug). The problem isn't in the code you've shown.

Comment: @Useless Added. I'll now try some of the hints.

Comment: Where do you use `c`, except as an index? It looks like you only need the `reverse_iterator` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `reverse_iterator`. If you want to keep track of an index, you can add a variable to your for loop like this:

```
int counter = 0;
for (xx::reverse_iterator it = yy.rbegin(); it != yy.rend(); ++it, ++counter) {
    // Do something
}
```

This is les error-prone than what you are doing.

Comment: I assumed he meant the index as if he was iterating forwards.

Comment: I was just explaining the method. Lots of people don't know they can increment two variables in for loops!

Comment: alestanis you're right. I didn't knew that before. @john but counter can also be the size and I'll decrement that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get these strange values because you have a bug in your code.

You can use a reverse iterator and get the index, like this

```
for (T::reverse_iterator i = x.rbegin(); i != x.rend(); ++i)
{
    size_t index = i.base() - x.begin();
    // Do something
}
```

The base method on a reverse iterator returns the corresponding forward iterator, subtract x.begin() from that and you have the index.

Comment: It should be `++i` in your code, and can't you just do `i - x.begin()`? I have never seen that `base()` method

Comment: `i - x.begin()` doesn't compile because `i` is a reverse iterator and `begin()` returns a normal iterator. base is the method that converts a reverse iterator to a normal iterator.